# avrdude: ser_open(): can't set com-state for "\\.\COM2"

Tags: arduino-uno

I have an unofficial Arduino Uno.

I've tested these:

> - Testing on USB 2.0 and USB 3.0
> - Changing Port (COM XX)
> - Updating drivers for the Unknown device to Arduino Uno (COM XX)
> - Resetting Arduino Board
> - Plug/Unplug
> - 1x PC Reboot
> - Burning bootloader
> - Changing 'Programmer'
> - Uninstalling-Reinstalling device
> - Holding the "Reset" button while I Upload
> - Testing different examples (Blinking/Voltage Serial Read)
> - Testing different "Board" in Arduino software (just in case, you never know)
> - Removing jump wires

Does anyone have any suggestion more than I just tried?

Comment: Which version of Windows are you on?

Comment: Arduino app is 1.6.9.

Comment: I asked which version of Windows you are using, not which version of the Arduino IDE you are using.

Comment: Oh man sorry, I was not very careful. Windows 10.

Comment: And what USB chip does your unofficial Uno use?

Comment: The board is similar to that one : (Same Brand, but for example behind the USB port the component's text says "U12.000\n r4 ON" where \n is new line)
http://www.ebay.com/itm/M-J-Duino-Arduino-Uno-R3-Compatible-CH340-with-USB-and-Serial-Headers-/311393221914
I don't know how to find the USB chip you're asking sorry. Send me instructions if the information I give you are not enough.

Comment: It's the chip nearest the USB socket. In that picture it's the black rectangle next to the crystal that says "12.000"

Comment: Thanx, I edited my previous comment with a liiitle more information. I suppose now you can post an Answer now that you have information about the USB chip right ? I mean I just want to reward you :D You already made me think about the USB chip, didn't think that clones used a different one.

Comment: I don't understand what you are describing. Please take a photograph of your actual board with a closeup of the USB socket area.

Comment: The difference I was talking about : http://prntscr.com/bfhnrq
The whole board : http://prntscr.com/bfho23

Comment: That's just the crystal. I need to know what it says on the chip. The big black rectangle just above the component you are describing in that picture. The one with lots of pins sticking out of it.

Comment: It says : Header is "WCH" and the rest "CH340G \n 202685413" with \n representing a new line.

Comment: I thought that looked like one of those... So... Have you installed the CH340G drivers? Or are you trying to use the genuine Arduino Uno drivers?

Comment: Thank you kind sir. I really didn't know that they used different USB chips. And that's because ? (If you can answer ... that would be nice :D )
I installed the CH340G drivers and now it works perfectly :D
Also "Answer The Question" so I can give you some credits if you want.

Comment: After spending hours struggling with the same problem, @Brew's response solved my problem! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The board you have uses the CH340G chip instead of an ATMega16U2 or FTDI FT232R chip.

It requires special drivers, not the ones that come with the IDE.

Why do they use that chip instead of the proper one? Simply because it's dirt cheap. They are the cheapest of the cheapest of the cheapest USB chips around. They frequently die. You might want to save up and invest in a genuine Arduino at some point, because that one may well die out of the blue.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with the cheap nano from Amazon Longrunner. At first, it worked, I could program it. Then, I farted around with my COM port numbers because I was tired of being in the COM14 area.
Since that moment, it stopped working. IDE couldn't find the port COM3. After reading you guys, I also noticed that the device was identified RAMPS which it wasn't before. I updated the driver which didn't work; it told me I was already with latest driver.
So I deleted that driver and reconnected my Nano and lord and behold, the new driver USB-SERIAL CH340 installed and everything was fine. El cheapo still works. I don't care to pay more just for the USB chip which I will use only once. The uP is still up to par.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. I was able to upload a simple Blink example, but not my own program. And I thought there's no problem in my program, since I successfully tested it on other Arduino before. But actually, that was the problem. I had this in my program (for console logs):

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}
```

Then I read that different Arduinos use different baud rates. Originally I tested it on Arduino Mega, but this time I wanted to upload it to "unofficial" Arduino Nano (for which you have to use `ATmega328P (Old Bootloader)` option when uploading).

Since I didn't need debug logs in my program anymore, I removed these 'Serial' commands completely. Then it got uploaded without problems.

[A short article on this topic](https://www.programmingelectronics.com/serial-begin-9600/)

Comment: so the upload goes to the bootloader, not to your sketch and the baud rate used by the IDE should match the baud rate used by the bootloader. The baud rate set in sketch is irrelevant

Comment: Later, I got this error for this board even without 'Serial' commands in my program. So maybe there was something more happening. It took me like 20 attempts to upload it to that board again. (Other board worked without problems). So maybe it wasn't actually related :-\